# jQuery dialog not showing the correct content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm doing a redesign for a site and I need to add a jQuery dialog for the shop. The problem is, when I click a certain item from the list, the jQuery dialog shows something diffrent. It shows the first item and when I press it more and more it continues showing them one by one from the first to the last. For example (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY1yl.png) I click on the third item and it shows the first one. I click on the third item again and it shows the second one. If I click it 10 times it will show the tenth item. I've been stuck with this problem for quite a while and I can't seem to fix it.

The PHP code that displays the items(whoever wrote this made a big mess): http://pastebin.com/jkuEMyCR
A snippet of the code responsible for the dialog:

```
        //                                     SHOP ITEM LARGE
    ?><div class="section"><?php
    print '<a href="';
    ?></div><?php
    //This is how it opened it before
//  print "javascript:regular('pages/item_large.php?shop=".$item->webshopMenu."&amp;nr=".$item->id."');";
    print '"><img class="save" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:0; padding-bottom:0px;" border="0" src="'.$img.'" alt="'.$item->Naam.'" '.$image_size . "</a>";
    print '<br><small>Artikelnr. : ' . $item->Artikelnr . '</small></div>' . "\n";
    //This is how I'm trying to do it now
    ?>
    <div style="display: none" class="dialog">
        <?php
        echo "<iframe src='pages/item_large.php?shop=" . $item->webshopMenu . "&amp;nr=" . $item->id . "'" . "width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0'></iframe>"
        ?>
    </div>
```

The JS code:

```
    (function() {
    $('.save').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var dialog = $(this).closest('.section').find('.dialog');
        $('.dialog:first').dialog({
            modal: true,
            scrollable: false,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            width: 450,
            height: 445
        })
    })
})();
```

Comment: In your HTML you have id="dialog" and in your JS you are calling a .dialog which is for a class. Also in your JS, I don't really get why you are doing a find on .dialog in .section and then applying your dialog on the first .dialog. Why aren't you just applying your dialog on all the items that have a dialog class

Comment: @JohnnyDew Oops, I copied an old code. Changed it with the new one, sorry

Comment: iframe? really? show us not the php code, but real html output you have please

Comment: I would remove the :first in your "$('.dialog:first').dialog({" call

Comment: @KimAlexander There is no real html output, that's how it is programmed

Comment: @JohnnyDew If I remove the :first it will open all the dialogs at once

Comment: You are suppose to apply the dialog on the item that should have a dialog.

Comment: @Denki no html? that is very interesting, could you send me a link to any example how client-side jquery works with no html page?

Comment: @JohnnyDew meaning ?

Comment: Do you reload the iframe each time a new item is clicked to display the proper content or you have a dialog box for each item?

Comment: @JohnnyDew It always starts showing them from the first item to the last. Doesn't matter what item I click on or if it is refreshed

Comment: I suppose you need to give the id of the item you want to display to your iframe by changing the src. The src you must be currently calling has all items. Maybe there is a parameter that you can add that will you display the current item or just a way to display only the item you need. pages/item_large.php?shop=" . $item->webshopMenu . "&amp;nr=" . $item->id . "' should not be displaying all the items.